# What is the difference between a vector space and the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I figured out the difference between a subspace and a vector space.. no problems but in the lecture the instructor starts by defining a subspace as a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Does anyone know perhaps they are one and the same? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector space is any set that satisfies the vector space axioms.  Vector spaces require what's called a field.  This field is where the scalars come from - the scalars that we use for scalar multiplication.  When first learning about vector spaces we mainly use $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ as the underlying field.

$\Bbb R^n$ is one example of a vector space (technically one example each for all positive integers $n$).

$\Bbb C^n$ is another example.

A more complicated example of a vector space is the set of all continuous real-valued functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$.

A subspace is just a vector space that is a subset of another vector space.  Note that every subspace is a subset.  But not all subsets are subsapces.  For example, $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq \Bbb R$, but $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a subspace because $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a vector space.

If your instructor specifically defined a subspace by starting with it being a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, then it's likely because you're only considering the vector space $\Bbb R^n$ in your class and ignoring the existence of all other vector spaces (which is fine for a first course, I suppose, as long as that's clearly mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim V = n$ then $V\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and any subspace of $V$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the same isomorphism.

However it looks like that your instructor wrote $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and assumed the context, i.e. category, you are working in. One normally says "let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subspace"